# Insert a row with default value column in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I am writing a program which uses a database with sqlalchemy as client.

Here is one of my tables

```
class DownloadRecord(Base):
    __tablename__ = "DownloadRecords"
    id = Column("Id", Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)

    download_name = Column("DownloadName", Unicode, nullable=False)
    download_date = Column(
        "DownloadDate", DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow, nullable=False
    )
```

the column `download_date` is defined with a default value, both here and in the server side table. Here is the definition of the column on the mssql server

```
DownloadDate DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE()
```

however I try to add the record `DownloadRecord(download_name="new_download_name")` and I get the following exception.

> sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (pyodbc.IntegrityError) ('23000',
>   "[23000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Cannot
>   insert the value NULL into column 'DownloadDate', table
>   'DownloadRecords'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. (515)
>   (SQLExecDirectW); [23000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client
>   11.0][SQL Server]The statement has been terminated. (3621)") [SQL: INSERT INTO [DownloadRecords] ([DownloadName], [DownloadDate]) OUTPUT
>   inserted.[Id] VALUES (?, ?)] [parameters: ("new_download_name", None)]

I also tried to make this column nullable but When I added the new row the `DownloadDate` column was Null.
How do I make it automatically use the default value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is incompatibility between the type of the column `DownloadDate` and the type of the value you give as its default value on the client side.

The type you used is `DateTime` (on the server side as well as the client side).

However, in the following code:

```
Column("DownloadDate", DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow, nullable=False)
```

the return value of `datetime.datetime.utcnow()` is a timezone aware object, while SQL Server's `DateTime` isn't.

I see two possible solutions:

1. Change the default value to a callable which returns a `datetime` object which is not timezone aware.
2. Change the type of the `DownloadDate` column to a timezone aware type. You can use SQL Server's `datetimeoffset` on the server side, and SQLAlchemy's `DATETIMEOFFSET` on the client side.

Take a look at [Microsoft's docs on date and time types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#DateandTimeDataTypes) for the full reference.

On another note, consider moving to a code first design, where you define your schema in one place.

Comment: `datetime.datetime.utcnow()` does not return an aware datetime object: "This is like `now()`, but returns the current UTC date and time, as a **naive** datetime object."

Answer (score 1):

Searching I found some people fixed by using [server_default argument](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.default). But this makes the database server responsible to assign the value.

```
download_date = Column(
    "DownloadDate", DateTime, server_default=text('NOW()'), nullable=False
)
```

Also according to [SQLAlchemy documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/defaults.html?highlight=schema%20column#sqlalchemy.schema.ColumnDefault), ColumnDefault class is equivalent and it also may work:

```
download_date = Column(
    "DownloadDate", DateTime, ColumnDefault(datetime.datetime.utcnow()), nullable=False
)
```

But, this uses a scalar instead of a callable.

Hope it works.